# How do I get an access token from AWS cognito using google sign in

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I have a react native app and a Node JS backend. The react native app makes a Google sign in request and returns an ID token. How can I set it up so that signing in through the app will create a user in my cognito user pool?
In Cognito, I have set up Google sign in set up as a social identity provider. On the browser, I am able to make google sign in requests, and it will automatically create a user profile in the Cognito user pool.

I followed this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider/

How can i achieve the same result using react native google sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is the architecture you want:

- Your apps use tokens from AWS Cognito
- Users can also sign in via other login systems

What this means is that you should avoid 'React Native Google Sign In', since it does not fit with these requirements. Instead your React app should only know about Cognito, which is also the technically simplest option.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

Have a read of the article and notice that my code supports federated logins but only points to Cognito.

- [Federated Logins Blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/)
- [React SPA Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/spa)